# R Shiny: No output if 1/2 inputs = 0, although the condition is part of else

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, output, paste

My R Shiny app allows inputs from 3 different material types.
Within these material types you can decide how many different materials there are and how many of the materials there are.
Based on the inputs, three different outputs are generated that calculate how these materials are packaged (How many pallets and how heavy are they).
I added a fourth output that sums the data from the first two outputs and adds the data from the 3rd output. The third is special data, so it is stated differently.

That means there are 6 different possibilities of inputs, assuming that you don't always have all 3 types of material:

> A, B = 0,
> A = 0,
> B = 0,
> A, C = 0,
> B, C = 0,
> C = 0

The calculation of the fourth output is interesting when the data of the third input (C) is available.
If C equals 0, then the output remains the same since A and B are just added together.

The calculation remains the same because:

> A + 0 = A,
> 0 + B = B,
> A + B = A + B

So I have four different output possibilities for output number four.

Everything works fine unless:
C = 0 & A or B = 0.
Then no output is generated at all. But why?

Code:

```
output$zusammen_ergebnis <- renderText(
        
        if (input$anzahl_sonder == 0 & input$anzahl_materialien == 0) {
          output <- character(0)
          
          if (dc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(dc, "x 20' DC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtdc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (soc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(soc, "x 20' SOC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtsoc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (hc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(hc, "x 40' HC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichthc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (kiste > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(kiste, "x Kisten | Kistengewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtkiste), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (length(output) > 0) {
            paste(output, collapse = "\n")
          }
        }
        
        else if (input$anzahl_materialien == 0) {
          output <- character(0)
          
          if (dc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(dc, "x 20' DC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtdc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (soc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(soc, "x 20' SOC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtsoc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (hc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(hc, "x 40' HC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichthc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (kiste > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(kiste, "x Kisten | Kistengewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtkiste), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (length(output) > 0) {
            paste("Palettenanzahl:", wechselrichterpaletten_gesamt, "| Palettengewicht:", round(wechselrichtergewicht_gesamt, digits = 1), "kg \n", output, collapse = "\n")
          }
        }
        
        else if (input$anzahl_sonder == 0) {
          output <- character(0)
          
          if (dc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(dc, "x 20' DC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtdc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (soc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(soc, "x 20' SOC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtsoc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (hc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(hc, "x 40' HC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichthc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (kiste > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(kiste, "x Kisten | Kistengewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtkiste), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (length(output) > 0) {
            paste("Palettenanzahl:", europaletten_gesamt, "| Palettengewicht:", round(europalettengewicht_gesamt, digits = 1), "kg \n", output, collapse = "\n")
          }
        }
        
        else if (input$anzahl_sonder > 0 & input$anzahl_materialien > 0 & input$anzahl_extra > 0) {
          output <- character(0)
          
          if (dc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(dc, "x 20' DC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtdc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (soc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(soc, "x 20' SOC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtsoc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (hc > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(hc, "x 40' HC Container | Containergewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichthc), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (kiste > 0) {
            output <- c(output, paste(kiste, "x Kisten | Kistengewicht: ", as.numeric(gewichtkiste), "kg", sep = ""))
          }
          
          if (length(output) > 0) {
            paste("Palettenanzahl:", europaletten_gesamt + wechselrichterpaletten_gesamt, "| Palettengewicht:", round(europalettengewicht_gesamt + wechselrichtergewicht_gesamt, digits = 1), "kg \n", output, collapse = "\n")
          }
        }
        
        else {
            paste("Palettenanzahl:", europaletten_gesamt + wechselrichterpaletten_gesamt, "| Palettengewicht:", round(europalettengewicht_gesamt + wechselrichtergewicht_gesamt, digits = 1), "kg")
        }
      )
```

I've tried many things that probably don't make any logical sense, but I'm desperate so I tried some things.

1. I created individual else if conditions for cases "A & C = 0" and "A & B = 0".
2. I suspected there was a bug with the weights and number of pallets being added up in the else statement. So inside the else statementI added another if else statement that sets the values ​​for the material that isn't available to 0.
3. I also thought there was a bug in the paste function and reduced the content to a single string and replaced paste with print and reduced the content to a single string again.
4. I built the output according to the same principle as the others and created an empty output vector and in any case filled it with the content of the paste function. At the end I put the Vector "output" in the paste function.
5. I mixed some of the not working solutions above.

With all changes, the output remained empty.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  When using Shiny, I would try not to use variable names `input` and `output` within your code unless referring the shiny objects of those names, there could be a conflict.